# regex for [25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500] with braces

Tags: regex

i'm trying to write regex for [25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500] date format include braces any one please help me

Comment: What are you going to do with the regex? Validate the format? Extract information?

Comment: for extract data

Comment: Welcome to  SO ! This probably works `\[.*?\]`

Comment: Is that the only text found? Or does it exist within other text. Give a valid, but small and to the point example. Have any conditions, different formats you want to handle if any. Be specific.

Comment: What language are you targeting? Perl? Put it in the tag line please. What have you tried also?

Comment: It looks like a fairly standard datetime format.  There's probably something specific within whatever language you're using to parse a datetime string

Comment: Thanq sln it works

Comment: Hi omegaman actually im using hive, to load data from a file so need regex

Comment: @mickmackusa thanq for that now it's not working, i want to partition the data based on year and month

Comment: We can help you if you edit your question to show exactly what you need.  Include two or three different sample inputs and what you desire from each.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will capture the month and the year:

```
~\[\d{2}/([a-z]{3})/(\d{4})~i
```

or if you want to match the full bracketed expression, you can use:

```
~\[\d{2}/([a-z]{3})/(\d{4})[^]]*\]~i
```

You don't say what language you are implementing this regex in, so I can't be too specific.

This also assumes that the "day" number is two digits.  If it can be just one digit, then use `\d{1,2}` instead of `\d{2}`

You can test, experiment, and learn from this link: https://regex101.com/r/iTGMho/8

Please update your question, so that my answer makes sense to future SO readers.